# How to force proportional scaling using Fabricjs?

Tags: fabricjs

There has been multiple changes in the Fabricjs API that affect the way  scaling points behave. One of the latest changes in version 4 (http://fabricjs.com/v4-breaking-changes) states that uniformScaling is now the way to go to force proportional scaling.

This is my test canvas:

```
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

And this is my simple code snippet:

```
const canvas = (this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c"));
canvas.uniformScaling = true;

const Add = () => {
  const rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: "yellow",
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    stroke: "lightgreen",
  });
  canvas.add(rect);
  canvas.setActiveObject(rect);
};
Add();
```

See a [codepen](https://codepen.io/_miki_/pen/PoONjMd?editors=1010) illustrating the issue.

Why are the control points for resizing horizontally and vertically still there? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `uniformScaling` property only determines the behavior of the corner resize controls. You can hide the side controls using the `setControlsVisibility` method.

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setControlsVisibility

```
fabric.Rect.prototype.setControlsVisibility({
    ml: false,
    mt: false,
    mr: false,
    mb: false
});
```